# Compare member function pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

Let's say we have a class `A` which has a method `void foo()`. I know that I can get the pointer to `foo()` by using `&A::foo`, but this pointer only seems to rely on the class type, not on the instantiated object. If we have two objects `a1` and `a2` of type `A`, how can we make a difference between the `foo()` method of `a1`, and the one of `a2` using pointers, member function pointers, or even pointer addresses ? Basically, I want to be able to get a pointer that refers to the `void foo()` method inside the `a1` object, which would be different from a pointer that refers to the `void foo()` method inside `a2`. Thank you.

Comment: Why would two instances of a class have different member functions?

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for function+bind but it's hard to say for sure without more detail in your question.

Comment: Actually, they don't. Both have the same member function `void foo()`, so that we can do `a1->foo()` and `a2->foo()`.

Comment: "I want to be able to get a pointer that refers to the void foo() method inside the a1 object" You must understand that there is no such thing so you cannot get it. There is only one `A::foo` method in the memory that serves all objects of type (class) `A`. That's why you **must** specify object to which you want to apply this method (for example in the form `a1->foo()` - unless that method is static. To answer question "how can we make a difference" - method get's "hidden" parameter `this` by which you know to what instance current call is made

Comment: Right, that is the point. They are the same, so why would you expect to be able to compare them as if they were different? If you already know that, I don't understand what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can make them different. a1->foo() and a2->foo() are basically same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused here about the concept of an object (or instance of a class). An object is like a blueprint of a class. *You cannot have different members / member functions for each object*.

for eg.

```
class A
{
  int result;

  public: 
  void add(int x, int y)
  {
    this->result = x + y;
  }
}
```

All the objects of Class A will have member variable result and member function `add()` in it. So `obj1->add()` and `obj2->add()` would call the same `add()` function, even though the objects itself would have different attributes from each other.

`obj1->add(1,2)` would result in `obj1->result` to be **3**, whereas

`obj2->add(1,3)` would result in `obj2->result` to be **4**.